# Using <a href> to link to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, href

I have a anchor which i want it to be linked to a LogoutServlet so that it will destroy the sessions and redirect it back to a login page.

LogoutServlet.java

```
package pkg;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LogoutServlet
 */
 public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LogoutServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    request.getSession().invalidate();
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

tag

```
<a href="/Assignment/LogoutServlet" accesskey="1" title="">Logout</a>
```

Is this the right way to implement it?? I used this but it did not redirect me to Login.html .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That will hit the `doGet` method not the `doPost` method. An anchor link like that is a HTTP GET request.

If you wish to make a POST request, you will need to submit a form to the servlet using method POST.

Move your code to `doGet`instead of `doPost` and try that.

Comment: Worked well. Thanks for the knowledge! I'm quite new to servlet programming. So please pardon me.

Comment: do we need to include the context path inside the link value like `"contextPath/url-pattern"`, when i tried a href with `"url-pattern"` throws **status 400** error and the url in the address bar will be without contextpath like `localhost:8080/url-pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

Use doGet method. a href will use GET method.